# Using fgets() in a proper way

Tags: c, embedded, chat, sizeof, fgets

We have a project for this semester in embedded systems programming (C). I made a client/server program(Chat program) but my professor said when i am using the fgets it is not resource friendly but i don't know why.

Here is my source:

```
if (argc == 4){
   strcpy(nick, argv[3]);
   strcat(nick,":");
}
else if (argc == 3){
    printf ("Please type your Nickname!\n");
    fgets (nick,sizeof(nick),stdin);
    nick[strlen(nick)-1]=':';
}
else{
    usage (argv[0]);
}
```

Comment: what is the type of `nick`? array or pointer?

Comment: I don't see anything wrong (or resource unfriendly) in your snippet. I'd (maybe) just save the string length in a variable for later use.

Comment: @pmg maybe not exactly related but a pointer `nick` will cause issue in `sizeof(nick)`, isn't it?

Comment: The nick variable's type is pointer.

Comment: Yes, `sizeof <pointer>` is wrong ... but that is not a resource friendliness issue: it's a plain programming error.

Comment: @pmg Agree 100%, but then, you never know, what is a _resource_ here. :-)

Comment: The professor *migh* mean that usually one uses a fixed-size buffer when calling `fgets`, and if the input is small then maybe a lot of the buffer-space is wasted. On small embedded systems that could mean a lot.

Comment: The code works properly but my professor said what if i give a too big nickname. (1.000.000 characters)

Comment: if `nick` is a pointer it **does not** "work properly".

Comment: You need to nail down a requirement or two: what does your professor want you to do with a long (1000000 characters) nickname?  Truncate it?  Return an error? Allocate 1MB of memory for it?

Comment: Really this is a question for your professor; did you think to ask him whet he meant? That is his job after all. The `fgets()` call will only ever read `sizeof(nick)` characters, so it is still unclear what your professor's concern is without greater context (though there are plenty of other concerns).  An "embedded system" that supports a process loader (implied by argv/argc) is atypical of most embedded systems and probably not particularly resource constrained.  I see nothing in this that teaches anything useful or specific about embedded systems.

Comment: I'd be more concerned about the `strcpy()` and `strcat()` calls - there you have no check that `nick` is large enough to take the `argv[3]` string and its '`:`' suffix.

Answer (score 1):

The solution is then of course to "manually" read the input, resulting in lots of instructions in C but being carefull with resources and CPU:

```
else if (argc == 3) {
    printf ("Please type your Nickname!\n");
    int i= 0;
    while ((c=fgetc(stdin))!='\n' && i<sizeof(nick)-2) nick[i++]= c;
    nick[i++]=':'; nick[i++]= '\0';
}
```

(This assumes nick is an array of characters, not a pointer. Otherwise the size of nick must be given as a parameter and `sizeof(nick)-2` becomes `nick_size-2`.)

Comment: I cannot see what has been achieved here in terms of "resource".  `fgets()` itself probably uses few resources - you have added an variable `c` and `nick` remains the same as it was (and we have no idea what that is from the code fragment provided).

Comment: @clifford, not much has been achieved. A call to strlen has been avoided.